# How to load images not to impact loading speed of my website without reducing image quality

Tags: html, image, performance, loading, pagespeed

In my website i have several images but the size of the images is 
quite big, while all of the website is loaded but images which make it wait until the images are loaded 
which takes take too much time making overall response time too big.

now one thing i have too make it's size small, it will reduce image quality but i don't want to loose image quality.

i have used file optimizer to optimize my images but was not of much help.
is there a good technique to achieve this.
any suggestion would be appreciated Thank you.

Comment: you can load them lazily. If you have too many images, you might need to unload some of them since the amount you can load is limited by user's browser memory

Comment: thank you lazy loading is quite helpful i am trying to make it work. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you should try lazy loading for loading your images.**

Lazy loading lets you serve up an image heavy website without having to suffer
with all the prefetching and loading of images that may never be seen by the user. 
This is especially helpful for single page websites that are highly visual.
here is an example of lazy loading https://appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled/

https://responsivedesign.is/resources/javascript-jquery/lazy-load-jquery/
lazy load a jquery plugin that lets do lazy loading easilly

i personally load images using jquery as

```
<img class="comp-logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300.png" data-image="images/company_logo.png" alt="image">
```

here in img tag i used placeholder holder instead of my logo image which load faster.

now using jquery i load images like so

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".comp-logo").each(function (index, element) {
        var self = $(this);
        if (self.is(":visible")) {
            var imgSrc = self.data("image");
            self.attr("src", imgSrc);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a great detail about lazy loading.
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/lazy-loading-guidance/images-and-video/

Answer (score 1):

First, you might consider using JS to asynchronously load the images. Besides that, compressing the image depends on the type of image used. PNGs (graphics) can be compressed with very little loss by using tinypng.com or image.online-convert.com/convert-to-png. As for JPGs (pictures) I don't know another method than to use image.online-convert.com/convert-to-jpg but that will introduce some compression artefacts. However these can be configured to make a big file size difference with very little (but still some) loss in quality.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the new the standard loading="lazy"-attribute functionality to lazy load images (and iframes if needed). Additionally to support older browsers as well, you could use this polyfill that I‘ve developed for this purpose: https://github.com/mfranzke/loading-attribute-polyfill